# java long term thread

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, timing

I am currently facing a challenge with executing following thread in my webapplication:

```
return new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long lastHeartBeat = -1;

                while (true) {
                    if (isFullAbortRequested()) {
                        break;
                    }

                    if (lastHeartBeat == -1 || lastHeartBeat + 1000 * 60 < new Date().getTime()) {
                        // once every x minutes send a "i'm still alive!"
                        DEFAULT_LOGGER.info("still alive!");
                        lastHeartBeat = new Date().getTime();
                    }

                    //DO SOMETHING THAT TAKES 1 MIN

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                        DEFAULT_LOGGER.error("CACHE REFRESH SERVICE DOWN");
                    }
                }

            }
        };
```

The problem with this one, is that after some days it just **stops** (without any known reason). Is this a "expected behaviour" on such "while(true) sleep" threads that they might be closed by OS (?) or anything else?

What would be a durable solution for this "check every second if you have to do something, and if yes, do it (can take 1 min). then wait a second before next check"? The actions in "DO SOMETHING" should never parallize or overlap, so they should be blocking for this thread.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does "it just stops" mean? It's interrupted? There is an exception? The thread mysteriously vanishes? ...

Comment: TL;DR: use a `ScheduledExecutorService`, or some other sort of scheduler.

Comment: wont the ScheduledExecutorService start another instance even if the previous has not completed yet?

Comment: How do you start this thread? Is it from your code, or managed by some app server?

Comment: @Niko read the documentation. For example, `scheduleAtFixedRate` states "If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute".